# Convert .dae to x3dom

Tags: collada, sketchup, x3dom

Is there a way I can render a 3D model (in .dae, I'm using SketchUp) into a x3dom? I looked up online, but can't find the way.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the `COLLADA` file in the `VRML/x3d viewer bscontact from Bitmanagement` (http://www.bitmanagement.com/en/download) and then "save state as" `x3d, x3dom`.

Or you can use the InstantReality framework and use `aopt.exe` to convert the collada file into x3d or in x3dom.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: If you're looking for a Mac version, it is there. Look in the dropdown.